Powershell - JSON data set - Foreach() then input AWSCLI
I have a requirement to list AWS accounts then get each account contact information. For this I have used two AWS Cli queries. First one executed well as expected whereas second one ran but output not.
So below is the approach I followed:
1. Fetched all the account details using a AWS Cli command saved as JSON Array object.
JSON object look like [{"accid":"587665"}, {"accid":"465465"}]  as $awsAccData
2. Iterate above Array object then input to another AWS CLI command
Foreach( $i in $awsAccData ){
       Write-Host aws account get-contact-information --account-id $i
       }


In this Foreach block I am only getting $i value alone not as a whole AWS cli query along with $i.
aws account get-contact-information --account-id $ [
aws account get-contact-information --account-id $  {
aws account get-contact-information --account-id $    "":""
aws account get-contact-information --account-id $  },
aws account get-contact-information --account-id $  {
aws account get-contact-information --account-id $    "":""
aws account get-contact-information --account-id $  },
.
.


I am expecting above query along with response. Can someone help me out on this?

Also, In addition to @Santiago Squarzon's excellent answer, Amazon has made powershell modules for this. Take a look at https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWS.Tools.Account/ Specifically the Get-ACCTContactInformation cmdlet. I use the s3 modules in my scripts and they are excellent.

Looking at the response from API_GetContactInformation_ResponseSyntax:
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-type: application/json

{
   "ContactInformation": { 
      "AddressLine1": "string",
      "AddressLine2": "string",
      "AddressLine3": "string",
      "City": "string",
      "CompanyName": "string",
      "CountryCode": "string",
      "DistrictOrCounty": "string",
      "FullName": "string",
      "PhoneNumber": "string",
      "PostalCode": "string",
      "StateOrRegion": "string",
      "WebsiteUrl": "string"
   }
}

You'll probably need to merge the .accid property value with the response itself into a single object. What you should do is first convert $awsAccData from Json into objects, then enumerate each object and pass-in .accid property value to the AWS CLI, then lastly convert that response from Json into object and create a single object using Select-Object:
$awsAccData = '[{"accid":"587665"}, {"accid":"465465"}]' # <- Sample data

foreach ($i in ConvertFrom-Json $awsAccData) { # <- Convert Json into objects
    $response = aws account get-contact-information --account-id $i.accid
    (ConvertFrom-Json $response).ContactInformation |
        Select-Object @{ N='AccountId'; E={ $i.accid }}, *
}

